# How do download url jad by code, don't use browser of blackberry?

Tags: blackberry

I have url http://m.kimkim.mobi/build/keypad/kimkim.jad, I don't want use browser of Blackberry. How do download application from url by code

Answer (score 0):

To begin with one does not install a JAD file. A JAD is a metadata file that tells the device, in this case the browser, where to get the software. So if the URL you have to work with points to a JAD, you will have to download and parse it to find out where the COD file is. Then proceed as detailed in [this knowledge base article](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/800332/800620/How_to_-_Programmatically_install_and_upgrade_applications.html?nodeid=1577335&vernum=0).